# Ajax verify page before executing

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax.php file to which all of my ajax calls point with an extra parameter of the script the current call demands to execute. My problem is that I want to limit some scripts to being executed by specific pages only, say for example `sendComment.php` should only be called from `www.mysite.com/user/{any user}`.

What I have done is put this code on top of every script that I want to limit:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'],'mysite.com/{page_allowed_to_exec_script}'){
    Then do stuff here
}
```

But what I've come to notice is that not all browsers support the HTTP_REFERRER ( I might have spelled that incorrectly, I'm writing this by memory ), and as well as not being cross-browser it's also a pain in the butt having to hardcode this stuff in all of the files and is going to be an even bigger pain when it comes to changing stuff.. I'm looking for  a way I can possibly have all the scripts in an array with all the pages that are able to execute them, and perform a check in the ajax.php file at start.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: In general you don't limit the *page* which can access a server-side resource, you limit the *user* which can access it.  Things like authentication cookies are still sent in AJAX requests, so you can restrict the user access like you would any other page request.  There's really no reason to restrict what *page* the request comes from.

Comment: No, I limit the page, not the user. I just gave an example with the user page. Same script `sendComment.php` should not be able to be called from anywhere else, say `www.mysite.com/home` for example

Comment: That's my point, you're doing it backwards.  Restricting the page is incorrect.  Especially since there really isn't a reliable way on the server to _know_ what the current "page" is on the client, if there's any at all.  Your AJAX services should just be API calls which don't care how or what they're called, aside from any necessary user authentication and authorization.

Comment: Actually the page doesn't really make any difference, I just want to code it this way so that people who try to mess around with my stuff wont be able to

Comment: Notice what you just said: "so that **people** who try to mess around..."  That's exactly what you should be restricting, the user.  If a savvy user has access to call a function then why can't they call that function?  If you're worried that they'll abuse certain calls in order to mine data or degrade performance then you can limit the number of times they use that resource in a certain time frame.  But why shouldn't a user who has access to a resource be able to, well, access that resource?  Don't restrict based on what the user was just looking at, restrict based on what they can access.

Comment: That makes sense, but if a user calls a script from a page that wasn't supposed to run that script, by modifying javascript, then how would I be able to know that they did that in order to take accurate actions regarding their access rights?

Comment: How do you manage their access rights now?  At an authentication level, AJAX calls are no different from any other page request.  They're still just HTTP requests with headers and cookies and all that.  So it doesn't matter how they made the AJAX call.  If the request is authenticated then it's a legitimate call.  You can't stop them from modifying JavaScript client-side or from manually making requests (they don't even need to modify any JavaScript to do this), but you can deny unauthorized requests just like any unauthorized page request.

Comment: offtopic, i have to ask why you have your tongue sticking out?

Comment: @David Oh, now I understand what you mean. I don't have trouble with user authorization, users cannot run stuff they have no access to. I just wanted to add a page-authorization, which may not really be necessary but it's just a little indulgence (not sure if indulgence's the right word) I wanted to add.

Comment: @DevZer0 Not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: @php_nub_qq in your profile picture

Comment: @DevZer0 Oh, that's not really me, come on? :D

Comment: oh well, your question is still interesting and it seems David has given some great comments.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: And you're by no means the first person who's tried it.  It's understandable, but in HTTP terms it's a bit backwards.  In general consider each request to the server (and resulting response from the server) to be an isolated event.  It doesn't matter what the last request was, or what the next request will be.  Each individual request is handled independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even all browsers may not send "referer" because of some kind of "proxy","firewall" or "security" suite strips it out or even changes it.So you can trust on it.

If you control the referring page you can use sessions, cookies or the URL to pass the information if you feel it's that vital. If it's absolutely vital, your only option is sessions. The other two can easily be removed.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I was hoping I wouldn't have to use sessions. I was avoiding that throughout the whole project :<